# Behat. Как сделать что бы отчет о результате прохождения тестов отправлялся на Email?

Tags: php

В общем у проблема состоит в том что мне некогда следить когда пройдет тест и каждый раз форсить виртуальную машину. Хочется сделать что бы результаты прохождения приходили сразу на почту. Как это реализовать? Кто может дать совет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите скрипт обертку на bash или python с алгоритмом:

1. Запуск тестов, весь вывод складывается в переменную.
2. Отправляется email, где тело письма это переменная, содержащая вывод
   тестов

И запускайте этот скрипт вместо тестов.

Answer (score -1):

Использую эту функцию под себя

```
   // Сообщение
$message = "Выводи результаты";

// Отправляем
mail('Ваш email', 'Тема письма', $message);
?>
```

Подробней можно почитать тут:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php

Comment: К сожалению, ваш ответ (в текущем его виде) очень слабо применим в контексте behat (хотя бы потому, что сценарии в behat описываются вовсе не кодом на php).

Comment: Ну а патчить сторонние библиотеки (например, добавив отправку письма в сам behat) - плохая идея.